# Nodejs TypeError: expressJWT is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

i'm pretty new on nodeJs.

I have an error that i don't understand.

this is my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "pangolinapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
 },
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
   "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
 "body-parser": "^1.20.1",
"chai": "^4.3.6",
"cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
"cors": "^2.8.5",
"crypto": "^1.0.1",
"dotenv": "^16.0.3",
"express": "^4.18.2",
"express-jwt": "^7.7.7",
"express-validator": "^6.14.2",
"formidable": "^2.1.1",
"joi": "^17.7.0",
"jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
"lodash": "^4.17.21",
"mongoose": "^6.7.0",
"multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
"passport": "^0.6.0",
"passport-local": "^1.0.0",
"uuid": "^9.0.0"
}
 }
```

This is my middleware auth.js :

```
const expressJWT = require("express-jwt");
require('dotenv').config();


exports.requireSignIn = expressJWT({
secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
algorithms: ["HS256"],
userProperty: 'auth'  
 })


exports.isAuth = (req, res, next) => {


let user = req.profile && req.auth && (req.profile._id == 
req.auth._id)

if(!user) {
    return res.status(403).json({
        error: "Acess denied"
    })
 }

 const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');next()

  }

 exports.isAdmin = (req, res, next) => {
if(req.auth.role == 0 ){
    return res.status(403).json({
        error: "Admin resource, access denied"
    })
}
next()
}
```

but it return this error :

```
  exports.requireSignIn = expressJWT({
                    ^

 TypeError: expressJWT is not a function
```

I don't understand because this code imports the

```
    express-jwt
```

module and assigns it to the expressJWT variable. i can then use the expressJWT function to create the middleware and assign it to the exports.requireSignIn variable. I'am stuck

i try to follow the documentation but i still have this error.

Comment: Should be `const { expressjwt } = require("express-jwt")`, or, if using ES6 imports, `import { expressjwt } from "express-jwt"`.

Comment: @mbojko This was the only example that worked with ES6. `import { expressjwt } from "express-jwt"` . I was trying to import it without the curly brackets and getting errors. thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because your `expressJWT` const is not a function; check the documentation for `express-jwt` for an up-to-date example:

```
const { expressjwt: jwt } = require("express-jwt");
...

// Somewhere in your code
jwt({ secret: "shhhhhhared-secret", algorithms: ["HS256"] })
```

Comment: i try `const { expressjwt } require("express-jwt")` and `const { expressjwt: jwt } requiere('express-jwt)` but i have an error that says `expressJWT is not defined`.  My secret is stocked in my .env `SECRET#123`

Comment: @Kame_Sensei `expressJWT is not defined` - try `expressjwt` instead of `expressJWT`.

Comment: thank you that was an uppercase error.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm using:**

- nodejs v18.16.1
- express-jwt v8.4.1

```js
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt');

const validateJwt = expressJwt.expressjwt({ secret: 'secret', algorithms: ['HS256'] });
```

Also change `req.user` for `req.auth` in your endpoint:

```js
app.get('/endpoint', validateJwt, (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('endpoint', req.auth);
  res.send('Ok');
});
```

Hope it works!